# YouTube webapp crashed after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: unity, 13.10, youtube, webapps

I have annoying issue with YouTube webapp, which I installed in 13.04. In 13.10 I noticed it don't work, so I remove the package with Software Center (unity-webapps-youtube), but the icon is still on list in the dash, and when I click the sound button, YouTube is still there. YouTube is still launching when I press those buttons. Even after few reboots, and reinstalling this webapp problem remains. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you uninstalled `unity-webapps-youtube` youhave to remove manually `YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop` from this directories: `~/.local/share/applications/` and `/usr/share/applications`. To do this you can use the following commands:

```
rm /home/radu/.local/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop
```

After this, YouTube webapp will not appear anymore in Dash (even if `unity-webapps-youtube` is installed).

Comment: yeah, that solved my dash problem, but it's still a YouTube 'section' in sound menu

Comment: @Roomy After a re-login it will dissapear.